# MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port -- Limit to number of POP3 requests that can be made?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was messing around with the JavaMail API and consistently encountered a MailConnectException and SocketTimeoutException shortly after trying to rapidly open many sessions (~50) simultaneously (i.e. tried to log in to many different mail accounts at once).

I never encountered these errors when logging into a single account at a time with roughly 3-5 seconds in between login requests.

Is there a quota that Yahoo, Google, and other mail providers place on the number of handshakes that can be made in a given amount of time for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP requests? If so, is there any way to get around this limitation?

Or is there something else entirely that might be causing the MailConnectException?

Comment: Almost every provider enforces limits on API usage for their services. Depending on the provider these will be communicated in their API documentation or not at all and you have to find out about them using trial and error and external resources. The latter can be frustrating at times.

Answer (score 0):

Providers typically implement at least 3 layers of service protection:

- Network layer; Most will implement protection against [SYN Floods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood).
- Authentication; Most will will implement protection against authentication abuse. Frequency/rate of authentication is probably just the tip of the iceberg here though. Reputation, diversity of geolocation, userid-to-IP patterns, and other factors are probably more prevalent for auth protections.
- Service/Protocol layer; Most will implement protocol specific protections against things like rfc violations, mass bandwidth consumption, and abuse/spam.

The best way to avoid them is to code in accordance with published best practices (e.g. rfc2683) and in a way that seems like you have a clearly understood purpose for doing what you're doing. For example:

- POP3 really doesn't have a good use case for needing 50 concurrent connections
- SMTP/Submission with 50 concurrent connections looks a lot like a spammer
- IMAP with 50 concurrent connections is *maybe* understandable if the client is looking to do a per-folder-session and there are 50 folders...but even then providers may choose not to support this use case and limit concurrent connections anyway.